# How to correctly interpret the likelihood function of a Markov Chain, $P_{\theta}(X_1, ..., X_T)$ vs $P(X_1, ..., X_T|\theta)$?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, stochastic-processes

Suppose $ \{ X_i \}_{i=1}^T$ are states of a markov chain and let $P_{\theta}(X_1, \ldots, X_T)$ be the probability of observing the path when $\theta$ is the true parameter value (a.k.a. the likelihood function for $\theta$). Using the definition of conditional probability, we know

$$ P_\theta(X_1, \ldots, X_T)  = P_\theta(X_T \mid X_{T-1}, \ldots, X_1) \cdot P_\theta(X_1, \ldots, X_{T-1})$$

Since this is a markov chain, we know that $P_\theta(X_T \mid X_{T-1}, \ldots, X_1) = P_\theta(X_T \mid X_{T-1} )$, so this simplifies this to

$$ P_\theta(X_1, \ldots, X_T)  = P_\theta(X_T \mid X_{T-1}) \cdot P_\theta (X_1, \ldots, X_{T-1})$$

Then, the likelihood function is then:

$$ P_\theta(X_1, \ldots, X_T)  = \prod_{i=1}^T P_\theta(X_i \mid X_{i-1} ) $$

where $X_0$ is to be interpreted as the initial state of the process.

**My question is how the above analysis works if we use the different notation** of $$P(X_1, \ldots, X_T\mid\theta)$$

being the likelihood function for $\theta$ instead. Then, won't be end up with:

$$ P(X_1, \ldots, X_T\mid\theta)  = P(X_T \mid X_{T-1}, \ldots, X_1, \theta) \cdot P(X_1, \ldots, X_{T-1}\mid\theta)\text{ ?}$$

Then, we will have:

$$
P(X_1, \ldots, X_T\mid\theta) = P(X_T \mid X_{T-1}, \ldots, X_1, \theta) \cdots P(Y_1\mid Y_0,\theta)
$$

But, I am not sure how to find $P(Y_1\mid Y_0,\theta)$ since it now has $\theta$ in the conditional part?

In other words, if we were to treat the likelihood as a conditional probability distribution, do we now have a different problem of trying to find the joint distribution of the states and $\theta$? What is the correct notation for using the conditional distribution notation for the likelihood?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The two descriptions you provide are indeed equivalent. Let me try to shine some light on what's really going on here:

Consider your second setup, $P(X^n \mid \theta)$ (we use $X^k$ to denote $(X_1,X_2, \ldots, X_k)$, with theta as a realization of some random variable linked to $X^n$.The sequence $X_1 \to X_2 \to \cdots \to X_n$ supposedly still forms a Markov chain, yet all the variables depend on $\theta$, so how come no dependence is introduced, i.e., how come we are still allowed to express

\begin{equation}
  P(X^n \mid \theta) = \prod_{i=1}^n P(X_i \mid X_{i-1}, \theta)?
\end{equation}

Well, that's precisely the notion of conditional independence. If $\theta$ **was unknown**, Markovity would indeed be lost, in fact

\begin{equation}
  P(X_k \mid X^{k-1}) \neq P(X_k \mid X_{k-1}),
\end{equation}

as more past samples ($X^{k-1}$) yield more information about $\theta$, which in turn yields more information about $X_k$.

On the other hand, **once you fix $\theta$**, i.e., once you condition on a certain value for it, you introduce your desired Markov chain as you cap the indirect link between the $\{X_k\}$ via $\theta$.

In other words, the first scenario you describe is merely a shorthand notation for the second one; one might use this to elevate $\theta$ to some kind of "meta-parameter".

A practical situation for the second scenario is if $\theta$ is known to originate according to some **prior** distribution $P_\theta$. Can you formulate the MAP estimate for $\theta$ if

- $\theta \sim P_\theta$
- Conditioned on $\theta$ $X^n$ forms a Markov chain?

Comment: I am still just a bit confused. Is $\theta$ here an actual parameter (like in a Bayesian setting with a prior) or is it just a fixed but unknown (i.e. frequentist) parameter with no inherent stochastic-ness about it?

Comment: Of course $\theta$ will have some random nature to it; not all observations of $X^n$ make all values of $\theta$ be equally likely. The point is that there is no difference between the two interpretations you ask about because you end up implicitly conditioning on $\theta$. You can safely think of it as a definition: $P_\theta(X^n) := P(X^n | \theta)$. Certainly $P_\theta(\cdot)$ is a valid PMF for all $\theta$, which is precisely the notion of a conditional distribution. The one thing you don't care about (or you don't know) in this setup is where $\theta$ coming from, i.e., its prior.

Comment: Are we allowed to think of $P(X^n | \theta)$ as a usual conditional distribution? I ask because $P(X^n | \theta) = \frac{P(X^n ,\theta)}{P(\theta)}$ and so if we fix $\theta$, what is the interpretation of $P(\theta)$ in the denominator?

Comment: Good question! I maybe should have elaborated slightly more on this but that's what the last paragraph is about: You need to know $P(\theta)$ (so called prior distribution) if you explicitly want to make use of it; this knowledge will originate from measurements, models or beliefs about $\theta$. Why don't you try to answer the question I proposed to you in my last paragraph to check your understanding? Additionally, try to think what $P(\theta)$ you would choose to make the MAP and ML estimates yield the same result.
If you have any further questions don't hesitate to ask!

Comment: One example: Say you wish to estimate the height of people in a certain region; you take a number of (independent) measurements $H_1, H_2, \ldots, H_n$ and assume that $H_i \sim P(\cdot \mid h)$. You could estimate the height $h$ by $\max_h \prod_1^n P(H_i \mid h)$ but maybe $n$ is too small to yield confident results. In this case you might consider to take into account knowledge about the ethnicity of your sample population: For example $h \sim \mathcal{N}(166\text{cm}, \sigma)$ (Australia, women). So you adjust: $\max_h \prod_1^n P(H_i \mid h) \cdot \mathcal{N}_\text{Australia, women}(h)$